# What event from a tkinter (Python) scrollbar can I capture and how can I do that?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have the following block of Python code.

```
universal_height = 500

foo_canvas = tk.Canvas(root_tab, borderwidth=0, width=1090, height=univesal_height)
foo_canvas.place(x=10, y=355)

vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(root_tab, orient="vertical", command=foo_canvas.yview, style="My.Vertical.TScrollbar")
vsb.place(x=1110, y=355, height=univesal_height)

foo_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
foo_canvas.configure(yscrollincrement='30')

bar_frame = ttk.Frame(foo_canvas, width=1110, height=univesal_height)
bar_frame.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: foo_canvas.configure(scrollregion=foo_canvas.bbox("all")))
```

Basically, when vsb is created and the user proceeds to scroll with it, I want to be able to capture the event that is generated and then do additional tasks in the background.  How can I do that?

I'm new to tkinter when working with Python, so I'm still trying to wrap my head around how tkinter should be used with Python.

I have tried to do what the below link suggested:

https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/entry-scrolling.html

However, I'm already using the command keyword argument.  I'm at a loss as to what to do next.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of capturing an event, have the scrollbar call a command of your choosing. There's nothing that requires a scrollbar directly call the xview or yview commands of a scrollable widget.

First, create a function that can be called by the scrollbar. It must accept the same arguments that the normal xview or yview commands accept. Then, it simply needs to pass those arguments on to xview or yview, and then do any other work you need done:

```
def vsb_callback(*args):
    # call the canvas method to do the actual scrolling
    canvas.yview(*args)

    # do any other work you want here
    print("vertical scroll")
```

Then, it's just a matter of configuring your scrollbar to call this command rather than the xview or yview command of the scrollable widget:

```
vsb = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=vsb_callback)
```

Here's a complete, working example:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

def vsb_callback(*args):
    # call the canvas method to do the actual scrolling
    canvas.yview(*args)

    # do any other work you want here
    print("vertical scroll")

def hsb_callback(*args):
    # call the canvas method to do the actual scrolling
    canvas.xview(*args)

    # do any other work you want here
    print("horizontal scroll")

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, background="white", width=400, height=400)
vsb = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=vsb_callback)
hsb = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="horizontal", command=hsb_callback)
canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=vsb.set, yscrollcommand=hsb.set)

canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
vsb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
hsb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

for i in range(100):
    x = random.randint(10, 990)
    y = random.randint(10, 990)
    canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x+10, y+10, fill="red")

canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks! This is a bit off-topic, but what is the "*" in front of args? What does that mean in Python? Embarrassingly, I haven't seen it being used with passed in arguments.

Comment: @gp443: it's the unpacking operator (also called "splat" or "asterisk" or "*" operator). See [Packing in Functions: args and kwargs](https://geekflare.com/python-unpacking-operators/#h-packing-in-functions-args-and-kwargs) for an explanation.